# Java collection - group by multiple attributes

Tags: java, collections, group-by

I have a Java class:

```
class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  int income;

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int income)
{
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.income = income;
}
```

I have a `Collection<Person>`, with 4 x Person objects:

```
  Collection<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
  persons.add(new Person("John", "Smith", 5));
  persons.add(new Person("Mary", "Miller", 2));
  persons.add(new Person("John", "Smith", 4));
  persons.add(new Person("John", "Wilson", 4));
```

I want to make a new Collection instance, but from the elements with the same "firstName" and "lastName", make 1 element, and the result "income" will be the sum of the "incomes" of each element. So, for this particular case, the resulting collection will have 3 elements, and "John Smith" will have the "income" = 9.

In SQL, the equivalent query is:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, SUM(INCOME) FROM PERSON GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
```

I found only answers which contain Map as result, and "key" contains the column(s) used for grouping by. I want to obtain directly a similar type of collection from the initial (`ArrayList<Person>`), and not a Map, because if in my collection I have millions of elements, it will decrease the performance of the code. I know it was easier if I worked on SQL side, but in this case I must work on Java side.

Comment: Note that most Java solutions will not use any of the heavy optimizations SQL uses. So your grouping equivalents will always be not as efficient, use maps in between and then convert everything to your desired output format. The alternative would be to use a library that offers SQL like syntax in Java, those may also use some of the heavy optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that is the most beautiful solution, but you can try to `groupBy` `firstName` and `lastName` with a delimiter between them, let's say `.`. After you collect your data into `Map<String, Integer>` that contains your `firstName.lastName`, you create new list of `Person` from it.

```
 List<Person> collect = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.getFirstName() + "." + person.getLastName(),
                    Collectors.summingInt(Person::getIncome)))
            .entrySet().stream().map(entry -> new Person(entry.getKey().split(".")[0],
                                                                      entry.getKey().split(".")[1],
                                                                      entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: *or* you need a `Holder` that has `hashcode/equals` like `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` or java-9 `List.of()`...

Answer (score 1):

I think **[JoSQL](http://josql.sourceforge.net/manual/introduction.html)** is your way to go here, it allow you to run SQL queries over java objects:

> **JoSQL** (*SQL for Java Objects*) provides the ability for a developer to apply a SQL statement to a collection of Java Objects. JoSQL provides the ability to search, order and group ANY Java objects and should be applied when you want to perform SQL-like queries on a collection of Java Objects.

And this is how to use it in your case:

```
Query q=new Query();
q.parse("SELECT firstname, lastname, SUM(income) FROM package.Person GROUP BY firstname, lastname");
List<?> results=q.execute(names).getResults();
```

You can also follow this **[JoSQL tutorial](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2014/04/josql-tutorial)** for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer below:

```
List<Person> collect = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.getFirstName() + "." + person.getLastName(),
                    Collectors.summingInt(Person::getIncome)))
            .entrySet().stream().map(entry -> new Person(entry.getKey().split(".")[0],
                                                                      entry.getKey().split(".")[1],
                                                                      entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Do not do that way! It uses memory a lot. Use Wrapper (PersonComparator) over the fields you need to group by.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("John", "Smith", 5));
        persons.add(new Person("Mary", "Miller", 2));
        persons.add(new Person("John", "Smith", 4));
        persons.add(new Person("John", "Wilson", 4));

        Map<Person, Integer> groupedByIncomes = persons.stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Person::getPersonComparator,
                                Collectors.summingInt(Person::getIncome)
                        )
                )
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e -> e.getKey().person,
                        Map.Entry::getValue
                ));

        System.out.println(groupedByIncomes);
    }

    static class Person {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int income;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int income) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.income = income;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public int getIncome() {
            return income;
        }

        PersonComparator getPersonComparator() {
            return new PersonComparator(this);
        }

        static class PersonComparator {
            Person person;

            PersonComparator(Person person) {
                this.person = person;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                if (this == o) return true;
                if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
                PersonComparator that = (PersonComparator) o;
                if (!person.getFirstName().equals(that.person.getFirstName())) return false;
                return person.getLastName().equals(that.person.getLastName());
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                int result = person.getFirstName().hashCode();
                result = 31 * result + person.getLastName().hashCode();
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need framework solution f.e. when you need some abstraction over the data types you have (SQL, Mongo or Collections) I suggest you to use QueryDSL: http://www.querydsl.com/

Comment: In my task, I have to use many groupingBy's for the same collection, so I cannot use the version with equals() and hashCode(). So, for now I'll try that answer. But if I'll have problems with performance, I can use more Compator classes?

Comment: equals() and hashCode() is for the custom comparator which reflects the group by criteria: firstName and lastName is the criteria - so these fields are used

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 streams' Collector's groupingBy:

```
    Map<String, Integer> sum = items.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getFirstName()+p.getSecondName(), Collectors.summingInt(Person::getIncome)));
```

Comment: Indeed useful and compact but OP says he searches for a solution not delivering a `Map` but an `ArrayList`. You may convert the result in the end.